# Asking for light novel or manga acceptable?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Is asking for link or DL links of light novel or manga acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's acceptable to ask for legal sources *only*.

Comment: Like for example: nyaa?

Comment: No, sadly Nyaa is not legal. We do have a working list of [some legal anime-related media sources](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/922/274), though.

Comment: Light novels are not acceptable? Because I was planning to ask some DL link of a specific light novel.

Comment: Light novels are no different from any other media; if the source is not licensed properly, it's an illegal source.

Comment: I see, so if I ask for a DL link and someone answered an illegal source will I get a downvote for it?

Comment: No. When you ask the question, you ask for a legal source. If someone posts an illegal source as an answer, they will get the downvote, not you.

Comment: You can always google the title.

Comment: @ton.yeung tried googling it but can't find english translations on that novel.

Comment: @キルア Alright thanks for the info, so which tag should I use when requesting for DL links? Ow and should I ask here or on beta?

Comment: You'd ask on the main (beta) site. You can tag it with [tag:resources].

Comment: @キルア Okay thanks